# Install Mathematica 11.3 on 32bit Lubuntu 18.04 not work default to 64bit version

Tags: linux, compatibility, installation

I'm recently installing Mathematica 11.3 on my 32bit Lubuntu 18.04.

The installer installs 64bit version of Mathematica in default, so I can not run the installed version.

Below is the error output of the installer:

```
WARNING: Failed to install WolframScript system integration.  See
/tmp/WolframScript-InstallErrors-8297 for more details.
```

But the error log file listed is empty when I cat it.

Below is the output when I run mathematica:

```
$ mathematica
can not find /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.3/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/Binaries/Linux/Mathematica
```

There is not a directory named Linux, but a directory named Linux-x86-64.

After consulting the [system requirement page](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/system-requirements.en.html?footer=lang) , I'm sure that Mathematica 11.3 can run on 32bit Linux. But they only tested it on Ubuntu 12.04–17.10, not on Ubuntu 18.04.

So my question is:

1. Is it possible that Mathematica 11.3 can not install correctly on 32bit Lubuntu 18.04?
2. What compatibility library do I need to correctly install the 32bit version?
3. Is there some option in the command line that I can use to choose the 32bit instead of the default 64bit version?

My system settings are as follows:

```
$ uname -a 
Linux **** 4.15.0-12-generic #13-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 8 06:23:34 UTC 2018 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

$ lsb_release -a 
LSB Version:    core-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch:security-9.20170808ubuntu1-    noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu Bionic Beaver (development branch)
Release:    18.04
```

Codename:   bionic

Comment: This is one reason why I'm still on 11.2.

Comment: @J.M. You're using a 32bit system?

Comment: Yep, I'm using a 32-bit netbook @anders.

Comment: @J.M.needshelp. good for you that your netbook appears to support OpenGL 2+. I'm stuck at MMA 9 since newer versions plot awfully slowly with GMA950 (due to software fallbacks).

Comment: This was the first question that came up when I googled "can Mathematica run on Lubuntu". For those in that situation, **I just installed Mathematica 11.3 on 64-bit Lubuntu, and it installed/runs seemingly without issue.**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As of version 11.3.0, support for 32-bit Linux has been discontinued.

Only 64-bit Linux is supported, and the system requirements page has now been updated to reflect that

http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/system-requirements.html

Additionally, I sent in a bug report since I believe the installer should have refused to run on a 32-bit system in the first place.