# Mathematica on Windows 98

Tags: windows, compatibility, history

I have Windows 98 computer. I would like to know what the latest version of Mathematica which worked on Windows 98 was.

Comment: Have you asked Wolfram Support?

Comment: They don't seem to know. All they said is that they only sell the most recent version (11.3).

Comment: I recall running Mathematica v.3  on win98, possibly even on win95 but I don't trust my recollection 100%

Comment: Do you hook that *dinosaur* up to the internet? :-0

Comment: Yes, I thought so, too. It might be a better strategy to install a light-weight linux distribution such as LUbuntu. Due to a [comment by @J.M. to this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/169214), _Mathematica 11.2_ seems to run under LUbuntu on 32-bit machines...

Comment: @Henrik, I actually was using a 32-bit netbook with Xubuntu, which is a different lightweight Linux distro. But, yes, I think 11.2 should also work on LUbuntu. (11.3 definitely won't.)

Answer (score 24):

It appears that the last version of Mathematica to have official support for Windows 98 was Mathematica 5.2.

We can see this by comparing archived versions of the system requirements pages for version 5 and version 6.

[Version 5](https://web.archive.org/web/20060813090011/http://www.wolfram.com:80/products/mathematica/platforms/)

[Version 6](https://web.archive.org/web/20070624132752/http://www.wolfram.com:80/products/mathematica/platforms/)

[image]

[image]

Comment: If 6 ran on ME there's a fair chance it would run on 98 as well.  They weren't very different